# Laravel 6 app_url set 2 domains

Tags: laravel

I have some domains that parked on one laravel project, ex:

domain1.com
domain2.com

app_url in .env set to domain1.com

When open domain2.com all of files & images open with url domain1.com. I want to when domain2.com open then files & images load in domain2.com.

How I can make it?

Answer (score 3):

You can set app_url dynamic in config

```php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == exmple.com) {
    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
}else {
    'url' => env('APP_URL2', 'http://localhost'),
}
```

in .env file set 2 domain

```sh
APP_URL=expample.com
APP_URL2=expample2.com
```

Answer (score 3):

In the RouteServiceProvider's boot method add this call `$this->setCorrectAppUrl();`.

And add this method to your RouteServiceProvider class:

```
    /**
     * Dynamically set app URL for correct routes building
     */
    protected function setCorrectAppUrl()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
            $host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "https://" : "http://";
            config(['app.url' => $protocol . $host]);
        }
    }
```